# What if Grout got Wet?

Tags: shower, tile, grout, sealer

I thoroughly scraped and re-grouted my shower and applied some sealer (standard unsanded grout and Impregnator 511 sealer), but I am worried I didn't mix/stir the sealer enough or at all (my memory/recall is really sketchy nowadays).  I am worried because I think some of the grout might be starting to erode or crumble away under squeegee action (this is about 2 weeks later).  Grout was allowed to cure for ~48 hours before applying sealer, and sealer was allowed to cure for another ~48 hours.

So...in a worst-case scenario where sealer was completely ineffective (i.e. grout is effectively unsealed) and I have been dousing the grout with water for a week or so: 1) is the potential wearing away of the grout likely in this amount of time? and 2) is re-sealing the grout after letting it dry out for several days an option regarding fixing the potential issue, or will re-grouting be required?

Comment: Sealers will not not cause grout to fail once cured. Not properly mixing the grout can be a big issue both with the appropriate moisture and through mixing. With showers I always use an add mix to help the grout hold up to moisture and be better all around. If properly mixed grout sanded or not it would not fall apart, a sealer would not affect the grout once cured. If I don’t have a modified grout ( I add add mix a fortified addition that does the same). It sounds like there was a problem with the mix, if it is soft it will be easier to remove and replace.

Comment: It's helpful to understand that lack of grout sealer application, or grout sealer not correctly applied, would likely not contribute to any noticeable grout failure at this point in time (i.e. a week or two after grouting)...thanks.

Comment: I >believe< I mixed grout correctly, including the time to slake, but it's hard to know that for sure now.  Given your input, my best guess at current time as to the explanation for some of the grout appearing to have crumbled away is that was how it was at time I applied sealer do to sub-par application, esp when wiping up grout "over-spray" - I may have been too aggressive with he sponge and wasn't wearing my glasses at the time so would not have noticed if I was pulling some of the still un-cured grout away at same time.

Comment: It occurs to me re: my 2nd question that a re-application of sealer -- at any time, really -- can't hurt so I'll probably go ahead and do that sometime in the near future.

Thanks for the helpful input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "grout... starting to erode or crumble away under squeegee action"

Don't blame the sealer. Your grout was not prepared and/or applied properly. Applying a sealer now may help stabilize the grout but your best option would be to... re-regrout.

Answer (score -1):

Success is highly dependent on you following the directions AND your application process.

There are many variables, including how porous your grout is...you may have used the wrong sealer or not followed the application instructions, including drying time, thickness of application, etc.

I’d re-read the instructions before proceeding:  https://www.1877floorguy.com/511-impregnator-qt.html

You may want to try 511 Porous Plus before re-grouting. That seems quite drastic.

Comment: Yes...possibly maybe to all that, but that is backward-looking/guessing.  My original question still stands, though.

Comment: @mblatz01 Yes...possibly maybe to all 3 of your questions.

Comment: There were just 2.  Do you have any experience that would shed some light on them?

Comment: @mblatz01 Question 2 is a two part question. Yes, I have experience in this field and my point is you’re asking if you’ll “have a problem over time”. I’d guess yes, but there’s too many variables, including your family’s habits, use, etc. AND as you say, whether you “mixed it enough”. Who knows...as you say, that’s backwards looking/guessing. Can you get a mill-gauge to test the thickness of your sealer? Can you re-read the instructions and confirm what you did and did not do properly?